# Metasploit Python module: "Unknown datastore option: CMD."

Tags: metasploit, python

In a Python Metasploit module that I'm developing, I am trying to use `CMD` as one of the options:

```
'options': {
    'RHOST': {'type': 'address', 'description': 'Target address', 'required': True, 'default': None},
    'RPORT': {'type': 'port', 'description': 'Target port', 'required': True, 'default': 80},
    'CMD': {'type': 'string', 'description': 'Command to execute', 'required': True, 'default': 'whoami'}
}
```

However, when I print the args, `CMD` isn't set to the default value:

```
Args: {'RPORT': '9999', 'VERBOSE': 'false', 'THREADS': '1', 'ShowProgress': 'true', 'ShowProgressPercent':'10', 'UNPARSED_RHOSTS': '0.0.0.0', 'RHOSTNAME': '', 'RHOSTS': '0.0.0.0', 'WORKSPACE': '', 'RHOST': '0.0.0.0', 'rhost': '0.0.0.0'}
```

And when I try to use `set CMD whoami`, I get the error `Unknown datastore option: CMD.`. What am I doing wrong? Am I only allowed to use certain names for my options?

I can see in `modules/auxiliary/admin/sap/cve_2020_6207_solman_rce.rb` that `COMMAND` is used as a datastore option, so I tried that as well and ran into the same issue as with `CMD`.

Comment: `RPORT` isn't the default. And you have 3 `rhost` fields. I think there is more wrong here than just the one field.

Comment: I set `RPORT` to that value, and for `RHOST` there are two set, one all caps and one lowercase, with a third being `RHOSTS`. Not sure why, but AFAICT those shouldn't affect functionality if I don't reference them. @schroeder any ideas what might be going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think you're done with troubleshooting. First figure out if your added code is actually being called.

Comment: It is being called, that's how I was able to print the `args`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the issue was the type of module created. My module that I wanted to use `CMD` / `COMMAND` for was in `auxiliary/admin/http`, which seems to not support that argument. When I moved the module to `auxiliary/scanner/http`, it started working like a charm!

For anyone else encountering this issue, also be sure that your module file is set to be executable with `chmod +x`.